# Finding Asymptotes

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I'm stuck at understanding why +c is the horizontal asymptote. Can someone please explain this? I get that the vertical asymptote is relating to (x+b), because the denominator cannot=0. But why does this kind of graph have a horizontal asymptote to begin with? 
[image]

Comment: What's $\lim \limits_{x\to \pm \infty}(y(x))$? Can $y$ ever equal $c$ if $a\neq 0$?

Comment: What happens to the value of $y$ as $| x |$ becomes very large?

Comment: uh... im not really understanding..

Comment: well from the graph you see that x is getting close to 2. But i don't understand how that value is due to the +c translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If $a$ and $b$ are reasonably-sized and $x=1000$, then what is the fraction $\dfrac{a}{(x+b)^2}$ approximately equal to?
- What about if $x=-1000$?
- Using the two facts above, what is $y=\dfrac{a}{(x+b)^2}+c$ approximately equal to for $x=\pm1000$?

This is the sort of idea you should have in mind when looking for non-vetical asymptotes (in particular, horizontal ones).